# f:ajax action method is not invoked

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, richfaces

I am using JSF2 with rich faces 4. My aim is to display a request ID that is generated from a method in the backend into an input text field using ajax.

Here is snippet of my code:

---

```
....
    <h:outputText value="Drawer No" /> 
    <h:outputText value="*" style="color:#ff0000;"/> 
    <h:inputText id="drawer" value="#{requestBean.drawerNumber}" required="true" 
         requiredMessage="Please enter drawer number">
        <f:ajax event="change" action="#{requestBean.generateRequestId}" 
            execute="@form" render="requestId"/>
    </h:inputText>

    <h:outputText value="Request Id" /> 
    <h:inputText id="requestId" value="#{requestBean.requestId}"  readonly="true" required="true" >
    </h:inputText>
</td>
<td>
    <h:message for="requestId"  style="color:red;font-size:10pt"/>
....
```

Bean:

```
public void generateRequestId(ActionEvent e) 
{
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    String emp=(String) session.getAttribute("loginUser");
    System.out.println("inside ajax event" + emp);
    try {
        requestId = AdminDAO.getRequestId(emp);
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

Once the method is called, it would generate a request ID which needs to rendered back to request ID.

This code is not even calling the method, and if I use `<a4j:ajax` instead of `f:ajax`, it is telling me that method is not present.

Comment: If any other ways to do this is also fine for me

Answer (score 9):

Here,

```
<f:ajax event="change" action="#{requestBean.generateRequestId}" 
    execute="@form" render="requestId"/>
```

The `action` attribute is wrong. You're likely confusing with `<h:commandButton action>`. You need the `listener` attribute instead.

```
<f:ajax listener="#{requestBean.generateRequestId}" 
    execute="@form" render="requestId" />
```

*(note that I removed the `event` attribute; it already defaults to `change` in case of `<h:inputText>`)*

And here,

```
public void generateRequestId(ActionEvent e)
```

The `ActionEvent` argument is wrong. You're likely confusing with `<h:commandButton actionListener>`. You need the [`AjaxBehaviorEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/AjaxBehaviorEvent.html) argument instead.

```
public void generateRequestId(AjaxBehaviorEvent e)
```

You could if necessary also remove it altogether if you don't need anything from it. It's optional.

```
public void generateRequestId()
```

#### See also:

- [`<f:ajax>` tag documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html)